# Viewing page locally locks up some browsers

Tags: google-analytics

I just started replacing my legacy Google Analytics tracking code with the newer "universal" code, and have run into a problem viewing pages locally. I'm not talking about using localhost - I'm talking about simply opening a page like **C:\My Documents\whatever\index.html**. No problem in FF28. Chrome34 chokes for a while, but recovers. IE11 locks up completely, and it's *Task Manager Time*.

The reason is clear - when viewing the page locally, it's trying to load the script from **file://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js**, which doesn't exist.

Does anyone know how to get around this? I do cross-browser testing before uploading my stuff anywhere - I really need to be able to view the pages locally.

I've found that replacing one chunk of the code snippet appears to work, but I don't know what bad effects it might have. Replacing this:

```
(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga')
```

With:

```
(window,document,'script','http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga')
```

Seems to work, but...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my approach will work, but only as long as I'm certain that I will *always* be serving my pages with the **http:** protocol, and *never* with **https:**

The "book" solution appears to be this:

```
})(window,document,'script',('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +'www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround to avoid the "local lockup" problem:

```
if(location.protocol!=='file:') {
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-999999-9');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
}
```